# How does the regex expression that checks for prime numbers work?

Tags: regex

I found a nice piece of regex code that checks for a prime number. I think I understand it but i'm still a little confused. Here's the code: `/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/`

Can someone explain (step by step) exactly what is happening both with the regex code and how it actually relates to knowing if a number is prime or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic premise is that this regular expression examines a ones representation of the number (e.g. 5 = 11111). By checking for the presence of ones (`1`) in certain positions or groupings it can identify the number as prime.

Additional References:

- Credit where credit is due -
  http://montreal.pm.org/tech/neil_kandalgaonkar.shtml
- Great explanation - http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/

Comment: That's an awesome write-up, but you should probably try to summarize or quote it.  The purpose of this and similar sites is to become a resource for finding information; if those links go away, your answer becomes useless.

Comment: @Brian, good point. However, this particular question is an exact duplicate and I've requested it to be closed. I was merely providing a reference for the user in the meantime. Furthermore, my summary would not be adequate for such an interesting expression. Nonetheless, I made an update.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dupe...I looked on stackoverflow and couldn't find a good explanation of 1) how looking at the bits translates into determining if a number is prime and 2) how exactly that regex works..

Comment: Er, that's completely wrong. You need to actually read the links you cited. It's a UNARY, not a binary, representation.

Comment: @dmd, you're right. Amazing you're the first person to catch it. See update.

Comment: I still don't think you quite understand it. It's purely a function of the NUMBER of ones. The string is solely made up of ones - the regex sees if it can be evenly matched by repetitions of "11", then by repetitions of "111", then "1111", etc.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I would suggest you just link to the two links you already do, and not provide the (wrong) explanation of your own.